# I want to know if i could declare 2 event listners with OR operator or anything else to load SAME function in just one line

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

what i am using right now

```
window.addEventListener("touchend", myFunction);
window.addEventListener("load", myFunction);
```

I want to know a way to add it in one line, since OR doesn't work,

```
window.addEventListener("load"||"touchend", myFunction);
```

Comment: As far as I know in vanilla JavaScript, each event type requires its own event listener. Unfortunately, you can’t pass in multiple events to a single listener like you might in jQuery and other frameworks.

Comment: `['load', 'touchend'].forEach(function(e) {
  window.addEventListener(e, myFunction);
});`

Comment: @mplungjan THANK YOU THIS WORKS PERFECTLY!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Type` is a case-sensitive string representing the event type to listen for. You can not define multiple conditions in it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters

But you can apply multiple listeners to the same function like this:

```
function addMultipleListeners(eventNames) {
    var events = eventNames.split(' ');
    var eventsLength = events.length;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < eventsLength; i++) {
        window.addEventListener(events[i], myFunction);
    }
}

addMultipleListeners('mousemove touchmove');
```

I hope, it helps you.

Comment: or just `['load', 'touchend'].forEach(function(e) { window.addEventListener(e, myFunction); });`

Answer (score 0):

According to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener it's not allowed